# Could not load NIB in bundle. Strange error. Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, nib

I have an app in the AppStore. I've changed some stuff and now I want to update the app to the new version.

However when I update the app, while the old version is installed and it starts running, it crashes with an error :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in
> bundle: 'NSBundle
> </private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5B180AEC-C797-4FEF-BB0F-CA6A0C31D4E4/SwipeBaby.app>
> (loaded)' with name 'NbE-fw-O9r-view-3qL-iW-Xaj''

If I then run the app again, all is good and everything runs smoothly. I haven't changed the names of .xib files I believe. And I don't recognize the name that is given in the error. It does start the LaunchScreen.

Could it be that a xib file is referenced somewhere in my code that I deleted in the new version, and then at the second launch of the app it gets ignored for some reason?
Is there a way to find out which xib file is meant by the error?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That style of name is used for objects loaded from a storyboard rather than a separate xib file.

Comment: Gotcha. That could lead to something. Thanks

Comment: @patturik 'NbE-fw-O9r-view-3qL-iW-Xaj' this is an id of element in your xib file, search the id in your all project you can find the xib file that has an error, goto the xib file and do right click on your xib's files owner icon you can see or figure out your error.

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar Thanks for the tip! I've tried searching in the project and in command line, but nothing turns up. I've also tried searching in older versions... Same thing. Also parts of the id didn't give me any results

Answer (score 0):

Found it :)

I was trying to add a subview to a ViewControllers view, that wasn't loaded yet.

What I did was I had a LoginViewController and passed it to another class called LoadNames as a delegate, so `var delegate: LoginViewController?`. Then I checked with :

```
guard let loginVC = delegate else { return } 
loginVC.view.addSubView(someView)
```

BUT I used the init() of LoginViewController to call this piece of code.. so the view of LoginViewController wasn't even loaded then. But of course the delegate didn't return nil either.

This piece of code was only called when the user updated to a new version. Therefore, the second time the app runs, everything runs fine.

I found out, because of Firebase Crashlytics.